# Is this sentence correct？

Tags: grammar, syntax

Would u please test this sentence for me？ '図書館でいお（ro）いろな教室でできないことができる' some of my mates said it is wrong while some said it is right

Comment: Is "いお（ro）いろ" supposed to be いろいろ?  Could you edit your post, if so?

Comment: -1 This question is badly worded, unclear and uses SMS language.

Answer (score 5):

> 図書館でいろいろな教室でできないことができる。

This is not grammatically wrong, but a little hard to understand. いろいろな教室でできないこと sounds like 'things you can't do in various classrooms' (The いろいろな looks like modifying 教室). If you mean 'In the library, you can do various things you can't do in the classroom' then you can say

> 図書館では、教室で(は)できないことがいろいろできる。
>   or 図書館では、教室で(は)できないいろいろなことができる。

If you really mean 'In the library, you can do things that you can't do in other classrooms' then you can say

> 図書館では、他の教室で(は)できないことができる。